# Jquery Images gallery

Tags: jquery

I would like to design a page to show images as a gallery..There should be some options like create albums with some of photos, and ordering the images in a album, adding caption to the photo.. for example lke Google + Photos...I am uploading images using dropzone.js

So please kindly let me know is there any plugins in jquery with above mentioned things..i know there have been lot of plugins for gallery in jquery. But i can not found the options like creating albums, adding images to albums....How could i get this things worked??? please suggest me some tutorials or plugins you found best..

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Plugins](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/07/42-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/). This link has many plugins that is related to the image gallery feature. But remember your need as a complete package cannot be found in a single plugin.

Another useful link:
[Package](http://visuallightbox.com/)

Comment: thnx for d help...I been searching on net....i havent found a one with creating album option in gallery plugins..all plugins are just to show images, slides option ...